# Multiplying a tensor by a scalar gives a tensor of Nans

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to tensorflow, i am trying to use Linear regression technique to train my module, but the function results a tensor of Nans! Here is the code

That's how i read the dataset

```
train_x = np.asanyarray(df[['Fat']]).astype(np.float32)
train_y = np.asanyarray(df[['Calories']]).astype(np.float32)
```

the weights initialization

```
a = tf.Variable(20.0)
b = tf.Variable(10.0)
```

the linear regression function

```
@tf.function
def h(x):
y = a*x +b

return  y
```

the cost function

```
@tf.function
def costFunc(y_predicted,train_y):
return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_predicted-train_y))
```

the module training

```
learning_rate = 0.01
train_data = []
loss_values =[]
a_values = []
b_values = []
# steps of looping through all your data to update the parameters
training_epochs = 200
```

train model

```
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
       y_predicted = h(train_x)
       loss_value = loss_object(train_y,y_predicted)
       loss_values.append(loss_value)

       get gradients
       gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, [b,a])
    
    #  compute and adjust weights
       a_values.append(a.numpy())
       b_values.append(b.numpy())
       b.assign_sub(gradients[0]*learning_rate)
       a.assign_sub(gradients[1]*learning_rate)
       if epoch % 5 == 0:
           train_data.append([a.numpy(), b.numpy()])
```

but when i print (a*train_x) the result is Nans tensor

UPDATE
I found that the problem is in the dataset, when i changed the dataset it gives tensor of numbers, but i still don't know what is the problem with the first dataset

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry, the mistake is silly, i had to re-initialize the variables every time by running the cells each time i run the script, because the variables had a value which results in  infinite values